# UriKind in windows phone navigation between pages

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8, navigationservice

I am a windows phone developer. I use NavigationService class for navigating to different pages. In this we use a UriKind property. What is this property actually means ?.. 
I googled it but not get a clear answer about it.

In msdn they provide as 
        RelativeOrAbsolute : The kind of the Uri is indeterminate.
    Absolute       :   The Uri is an absolute Uri.
    Relative       :   The Uri is a relative Uri.

But I don't understand it yet.. Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically Uri will will be used to fetch the information from the specified path. In that UriKind will decide whether the patch is Absolute or Relative.

**Relative Uri** : - This Uri will not be having the detailed information about the file path like.

```
/Images/Nature.png
```

**Absolute Uri** : - This Uri will give the detailed information about the file path from the foot itself.

```
D:/Projects/TestingApplication/Images/Nature.png
```

**Relative Or Absolute** : - This Uri might be Relative or Absolute that means Indeterminate